# ASP MVC3: Accessing Database in Index file- There is already an object named 'Model Name' in the database

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, model

I created a model class, ClassOne, for my database as follows

```
public class ClassOne
{
    [Key]
    public int primary { get; set; }
    public string column1 { get; set; }
    public string column2 { get; set; }
    public string column3 { get; set; }

}
```

Then in a DAL folder I created, i added the following code

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ClassOne> ClassOnes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

And I set up my connection string in my web.config

Instead of adding a controller for the model ClassOne, I want to access the data from my project's home controller file, in the index method. So I added the code

```
private ProjectContext db = new ProjectContext();
```

Hand my index method return statement is

```
return(db.ClassOnes.ToList());
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error message:

> There is already an object named 'ClassOne' in the database.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is already an object named 'ClassOne' in the database.

ANd it points to my return statement in the homecontroller.cs file:

> return(db.ClassOnes.ToList());

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Seems like you try to create a database that already exists. Try to change the DbInitializer to a more appropriate one.

Comment: What do you mean please?

Comment: I mean that you created a database using your ProjectContext or using another way and your code is trying to create it again and therefore it fails. To fix that take a look at EntityFramework documentation of Database.SetInitializer method.

Comment: What I am trying to do is just get the data from the database that exists on the server. I create the connecting string and the database object from the model and now I want to retrieved the data from the object. Is there a way of doing this that I am missing? Where can I find the EntityFramework documentation of Database.SetInitializer method

Comment: can you show the full stack trace? Are there any other controller actions that complete successfully? If so please show them in your question.

Comment: The documentation of Database.SetInitializer is at the following location: http://tinyurl.com/cuptz92